# Is there a pythonic way to do a contingency table in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe that looks like this:

```
            A   B      
2005-09-06  5  -2  
2005-09-07 -1   3  
2005-09-08  4   5 
2005-09-09 -8   2
2005-09-10 -2  -5
2005-09-11 -7   9 
2005-09-12  2   8  
2005-09-13  6  -5  
2005-09-14  6  -5
```

Is there a pythonic way to create a 2x2 matrix like this:

```
    1  0
 1  a  b
 0  c  d
```

Where:

a = number of obs where the corresponding elements of column A and B are both positive.

b = number of obs where the corresponding elements of column A are positive and negative in column B.

c = number of obs where the corresponding elements of column A are negative and positive in column B.

d = number of obs where the corresponding elements of column A and B are both negative.

For this example the output would be:

```
    1  0
 1  2  3
 0  3  1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let us call your dataframe `data`. Try

```
a = data['A']>0
b = data['B']>0
data.groupby([a,b]).count()
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer: please leave a comment - why.

Comment: This answer creates a dataframe with two indices, and not the desired contingency table format where those two indices are in X and Y axis respectively

Answer (score 38):

Probably easiest to just use the pandas function `crosstab`. Borrowing from Dyno Fu above:

```py
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
table = """dt          A   B
2005-09-06  5  -2
2005-09-07 -1   3
2005-09-08  4   5
2005-09-09 -8   2
2005-09-10 -2  -5
2005-09-11 -7   9
2005-09-12  2   8
2005-09-13  6  -5
2005-09-14  6  -5
"""
sio = StringIO(table)
df = pd.read_table(sio, sep=r"\s+", parse_dates=['dt'])
df.set_index("dt", inplace=True)

pd.crosstab(df.A > 0, df.B > 0)
```

Output:

```
B      False  True 
A                  
False      1      3
True       3      2

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Also the table is usable if you want to do a Fisher exact test with `scipy.stats` etc:

```
from scipy.stats import fisher_exact
tab = pd.crosstab(df.A > 0, df.B > 0)
fisher_exact(tab)
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a really useful page about the pandas crosstab function:

https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_crosstabs/

So I think for what you'd like to do you should use

```
import pandas as pd
pd.crosstab(data['A']>0, data['B']>0)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: updated link (I think) https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_crosstabs/

Comment: @user2682863 Both links are dead :(

Answer (score 6):

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

table = """dt          A   B
2005-09-06  5  -2
2005-09-07 -1   3
2005-09-08  4   5
2005-09-09 -8   2
2005-09-10 -2  -5
2005-09-11 -7   9
2005-09-12  2   8
2005-09-13  6  -5
2005-09-14  6  -5
"""
sio = StringIO(table)
df = pd.read_table(sio, sep=r"\s+", parse_dates=['dt'])
df.set_index("dt", inplace=True)

a = df['A'] > 0
b = df['B'] > 0
df1 = df.groupby([a,b]).count()
print df1["A"].unstack()
```

output:

```
B      False  True
A
False      1      3
True       3      2
```

this is just lnanenok's answer and using `unstack()` to make it more readable. credit should go to lanenok.